# Android keyboardview key long press action

Tags: android, xamarin.android, custom-keyboard

I've added a keyboard view to my android app and I want long press action for one key, but can't get that even.

Only these are present:

```
public void OnKey([GeneratedEnum] Android.Views.Keycode primaryCode, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Views.Keycode[] keyCodes)
public void OnPress([GeneratedEnum] Android.Views.Keycode primaryCode)
public void OnRelease([GeneratedEnum] Android.Views.Keycode primaryCode)
public void OnText(ICharSequence text)
public void SwipeDown()
public void SwipeLeft()
public void SwipeRight()
public void SwipeUp()
```

How to get long press key event?

Comment: What about the  [`OnLongPress()` method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.InputMethodServices.KeyboardView.OnLongPress/p/Android.InputMethodServices.Keyboard+Key/)? Are you saying you're having trouble overriding it?

Comment: It doesn't has it's own override long press event.

Comment: Look under "Protected Methods": https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.InputMethodServices.KeyboardView/.